# How to get result from an activity that received a new Intent

Tags: android

I have an activity A that launches activity B for results. Activity B launches another activity C. C launches activity B again with clear top flag.

Now when I finish activity B with `setResult(RESULT_OK)`, I receive 0 `(RESULT_CANCELLED)` in activity A.

How can I get the same result in activity A from B ?

Comment: To understand do you want activity A to receive a result from activity B even when activity B is launched with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag ?

Comment: Yes thats right.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach -

In activity B, we use `startActivityForResult()` to launch activity C and pass request code used to identify the result when it is returned:

```
// Launch activity C for a result
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActC.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_C)
```

In activity C, we can use the setResult() method to set the result code and any data that needs to be returned to activity B when it finishes. For example:

```
// Set the result code and data to be returned to activity B
Intent result = new Intent();
result.putExtra(EXTRA_RESULT, resultData);
setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
// Finish activity C
finish();
```

then in activity B, we can implement the `onActivityResult()` method to handle the result when it is returned from activity C. In this method, you can use the getIntent() method to retrieve the result data:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check if the result is from activity C
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_C) {
        // Check if the result was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the result data from the intent
            String result = data.getStringExtra(EXTRA_RESULT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you kartik for the answer but where are we sending data to Activity A ? and how can A receive the correct data from B ? As far as I can see, B was already launched by A for results.

Answer (score 0):

Well I eventually was able to solve the problem by consulting a friend.
I was using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` only before but now I am using two flags and it resolved my issue

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```